# Function is exceeding SQL’s 1024 column limit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

Parameters: `@Year int, @Month int`

Environment: SQL Server 2008 R2, Visual Studio

Developing a statistical report to find a 6 month average for each code type (about 50+ types) depending on the selected month and year.

So for example if February 2012 is selected then the query will count every time a code type appears in January 2012, December/November/October/September/August 2011 then divide that sum by 6 to get the past 6 month average. The actual average is calculated in a dataset in Visual Studio.

The SQL code looks something like this:

```
CASE WHEN TypeCode = "xyz" and [Year] = (@Year - 1) and [Month] in (12, 11, 10, 
9, 8, 7) then 1 else 0 end as TypeXYZ_Jan_Avg,

CASE WHEN TypeCode = "xyz" and (([Year] = (@Year ) and [Month] = 1) OR 
([Year] = @Year and [Month] in (12, 11, 10, 9, 8)) 
then 1 else 0 end as TypeXYZ_Feb_Avg,

CASE WHEN TypeCode = "xyz" and ([Year] = @Year and [Month] in (11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 
6)) then 1 else 0 end as TypeXYZ_Dec_Avg
```

This is done for each 50+ code types.

There are other fields in this function (not mentioned here) that I need to keep. Anyhow, the final query exceeds the maximum amount of columns permitted.

I tried to minimize the amount of fields by making the code type a parameter.

Something like this:

```
CASE WHEN TypeCode = @CodeType and ([Year] = @Year and [Month] in (11, 10, 9, 
8, 7, 6)) then 1 else 0 end as Type_Dec_Avg
```

However, this doesn’t work when I declare the `@CodeType` parameter in the function (because of a multi-valued error I get in VS):

```
 SELECT * FROM CodeTypes(@CodeType, @Year, @Month)
```

Values are passed but the calculations are off:

```
 SELECT * FROM CodeTypes(@Year, @Month) WHERE CodeType in (@CodeType)
```

Any suggestions? Maybe make a temp table? I’m not too familiar with how to do this but I plan to do some research right now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Work on building a query that produces only four columns:  month, year, code, and value. I think you'll find this query is much simpler in the end, as well, and also much easier for Visual Studio to process.

Answer (score 0):

Way vague but let me give it a try

```
   select c1.codeType, sum(c2.sales)/6
   from code c1 
   join code c2
   on c2.codeType = c1.codeType 
   and DateDiff(mm, c1.date, c2.date) <= 6 
   group by c1.codeType
```